# Getting the musical data of an iPod-track

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipod

How can I get the content (raw/sample data) of an iPod-track? I've seen apps like "Ringtone Designer" and iMovie which can do it, but I have no idea which api they use or what they do. I could imagine that iMovie uses private apis, but "Ringtone Designer" is a third-party app, so it must be possible with the public api-functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't done this myself but according to the documentation these are the steps (roughly):

1. Create an `MPMediaQuery` to retrieve one or more `MPMediaItem` objects from the iPod library.
2. Ask those media items for their URL with `-[MPMediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]`.
3. Create an `AVURLAsset` from the URL.
4. Create an instance of `AVAssetReader` for the asset.
5. Create one or more instances of `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` (one for each track of the asset) and add them to the asset reader with `-[AVAssetReader addOutput:]`.
6. Call `-[AVAssetReader startReading]`.
7. Call `-copyNextSampleBuffer` for each of your `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` objects until you have read all the data.

See the documentation to all these classes for details.

Comment: Would you provide sample code? please, or reference

Comment: Exists some sample code with a full processes of library music playback? Listing all artists, select one, list of all albums, select one or select all songs and finally all songs? Exactly the same as old iPod classics?