# Starting an AVAssetReader stopping callbacks to a Remote I/O AudioUnit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audiounit

I am using an AVAssetReader to read the audio out of the iPod Library.  ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905240/getting-the-musical-data-of-an-ipod-track))  I then take the read buffer and play it through an AudioUnit.  I am trying to refractor the code to stream in the Audio as I play it out.  However if an AVAssetReader is running the AudioUnit stops receiving calls to its kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback.

I have simplified my code to only play a file within the AudioUnits callback...

```
OSStatus UnitRenderCB(void* pRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags* flags, const AudioTimeStamp* timeStamp, UInt32 busNum, UInt32 numFrames, AudioBufferList*  pData){

    OSStatus tErr = noErr;
    MySoundStream* pS = (MySoundStream*)pRefCon;

    ExtAudioFileRead(pS->InRef, &numFrames, pData);     // Here's the MP3/WAV/etc Data loaded...

    if (numFrames <= 0){    // EOF?
        ExtAudioFileSeek(pS->InRef, 0);
        return 1;
    }

    return tErr;
}
```

and then I call this code and the AudioUnit stops playing, the UnitRenderCB is no longer called.

```
    NSError* error = nil;
    AVAssetReader* reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:songURL error:&error];

    {
        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput* output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:songTrack outputSettings:outputSettingsDict];
        [reader addOutput:output];
        [output release];
    }


    [reader startReading];

    [reader cancelReading];

    [reader release];
```

I am using the same AudioUnit setup as is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130443/audiounits-causing-universal-skipping-after-returning-from-springboard)

Does the AVAssetReader use the AudioUnit systems?  Is there no way to make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an AudioSession and set a mixable category, described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html) under "Working with Music Players".

This document actually describes how to configure your AudioSession for use with the MediaPlayer framework, but it applies equally well to AVAssetReader.

Comment: I was using 'kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory - kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback' so I needed to ensure that 'kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers' was set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have called 'AudioSessionInitialize' without it strange things can occur.