# AudioSession Settings for RemoteIO to play nice with iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiounit, audiosession

As I previously found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209565/starting-an-avassetreader-stopping-callbacks-to-a-remote-i-o-audiounit).

If you start running an AVAssetReader while using a Remote I/O callback to play audio, starting the AVAssetReader will block the Remote I/O callback unless you allow iPod mixing with...

```
UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof(audioCategory),&audioCategory);

AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof (UInt32), &(UInt32) {1});
```

However I am finding that this prevents the use of Audio Remote Control calls as setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209565/starting-an-avassetreader-stopping-callbacks-to-a-remote-i-o-audiounit).

So...

- I need "MixWithOthers" ON to use an AVAssetReader
- I need "MixWithOthers" OFF to use Audio Remote Controls

Does anyone know of how I can setup my AudioSession so I can use both?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am processing audio with an Audio Unit callback as I read from the iPod library using AVAssetReader. If I do not set MixWithOthers to TRUE each read from AVAssetReader interrupts playback. I am considering a different approach to see if it works. Specifically if I use Audio Queue Services and not Audio Units I wonder if it will work. Have you had any success?

Comment: When I have MixWithOther TRUE my AVAssetReaders mix with playback but RemoteAudio controls don't work.  When I have MixWithOther FALSE I have the AVAssetReader interrupting the playback.  I had the same result with Audio Queues, but do tell me if it works for you.

Comment: It appears another app which also processes audio from the iPod library also have the same problem with remote events being blocked when MixWithOthers is used. I think there needs to be a new audio setting that enables AVAssetReader in the same as a running Audio Unit. It appears many apps want to make use of this combination of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now in iOS 5.   The correct handling is to leave MixWithOthers OFF.  The AVAssetReader will no longer stop the callbacks of your audio playback.